# Dynamically making side bar menu as active

Tags: angularjs, sidebar

I am having one master page which has sidebar menu items and footer.I am using this sidebar in other pages.After I login Dashboard menu gets highlighted its because i am making it active.But after clicking on other links how can i make that menu active because i am using one sidebar common for all pages.Is there any way I can do it dynamically?
Or do i have to copy the below code in every page and make particular menu item active?

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="LeftMenu">
    <ul>
    <a href="#!/admindashboardhome" title="Dashboard"><li 
    class="Active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    <span>Dashboard</span></li></a>
    <a href="#!/examinationhalltickets" title="Declaration"><li><span
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span><span>Examination
    Form</span></li></a>
    <a href="#!/collegedetails" title="Declaration"><li><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span><span>College 
    Details</span></li></a>
    <a href="#!/studentdetails" title="Declaration">
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span>Student
    Details</span></li></a>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `location.hash`, `$location`.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit please

Comment: Do i have to use it in <a> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

HTML:

```
<a ng-class="getClass('/admindashboardhome')" href="/admindashboardhome">Dashboard</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.getClass = function (path) {
  return ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) ? 'active' : '';
}
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  //styling
}
```

Comment: @SachinHR you should have one controller for that menu so you would only need to have that code in there once - that would be the easiest way to handle it. Let me know if that makes sense. Make sure to upvote/accept the answer if it works for you! :)

Comment: If you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) of your code I can edit it to work.

Comment: In my html <a ng-class="getClass('/admindashboardhome')" href="#!/admindashboardhome"><li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span><span>Dashboard</span></li></a>.In my controller.js I pasted the js code and in my CSS i have like this  li.active > a /* .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus */ {
    color: #d63932; cursor: default; background-color: transparent; border: 0px solid #fff; border-bottom-color: #d63932; border-bottom:solid 3px #d63932!important; }
But right now it is not highlighting dashboard

Comment: Css is not getting applied

Comment: You don't need all that in the css. Just add the .active and put your styling (that you listed in your comment) in it.

Comment: If you upload a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) I can edit it to show you, but it's just like I said in my post.

Comment: I have uploaded two files.admindashboard.html is my html and navController.js is my js file.In <ul> i have given ng-controller="navController".In html only i am defining css also

Comment: @SachinHR doesn't appear to be a working plunker... you should be able to run the application and see it working.